# Como usar função de comparação em um std::sort

Tags: c++, vector

No código abaixo o programa deve ordenar o vector `campanha` se baseando na quantidade de votos de cada vereador:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

struct Vereador
{
    string nome;
    int votos;
};


int main()
{
    vector<Vereador> campanha
    {
        { "Angelo Orlando", 6580 },
        { "Paulo Furini",   3985 },
        { "Augusto Jacob",  9025 },
        { "Chico Sardelli", 5900 }
    };
    
    sort( campanha.begin(), campanha.end(),
        []( Vereador x, Vereador y ){ return x.votos > y.votos; } );
    
    
    for( auto i: campanha )
        cout << "Candidato: " << i.nome << "\tVotos: " << i.votos << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Eu estou com dúvida de como funciona essa função de comparação que é usada no sort na linha:

```
sort( campanha.begin(), campanha.end(),
                []( Vereador x, Vereador y ){ return x.votos > y.votos; } );
```

Quais argumentos estariam recebendo os parâmetros `x` e `y`? e como o sort iria usar o valor do retorno para ordenar o vector?

Comment: O _sorting algorithm_ utilizado pela função `sort` basicamente vai chamar a função que você passou. Se retornar `true`, considera-se o _primeiro_ parâmetro _menor_ que o segundo (ele virá antes no vetor). Se retornar `false`, considera-se o _primeiro_ parâmetro _maior_ que o segundo. É uma função genérica de comparação. Agora perguntar _quando_ essa função é chamada varia de algoritmo para algoritmo. Veja um _pseudo-código_ do [_quick sort_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort): onde é feita uma comparação é _provavelmente_ o local onde a sua _lambda_ seria chamada.

Comment: Devo salientar que não há garantia que a implementação de `sort` de fato utiliza o algoritmo _quick sort_. A especificação da linguagem (desde C++ 11) só postula a complexidade que `sort` deve assumir, `O(N * log(N))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sou um especialista em C++11, mas esse código tem algumas premissas que são tranquilas de entender.

O primeiro ponto aqui é em relação à sintaxe, `[]( Vereador x, Vereador y ){ return x.votos > y.votos; }`. Isso é uma [expressão lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/4438007). Ela é uma função anônima criada unicamente para ser descartada, como se fosse uma variável sem maior importância, como a variável `auto i` que você criou no seu código.

Na documentação do próprio [C++ sobre `sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), você está usando a sobrecarga `template< class RandomIt, class Compare > void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );`, onde você passa o iterador que marca o começo, o iterador que marca o fim e uma função de comparação. Na documentação, ele explica que `comp` é uma função que pega dois valores para comparar e retorna verdade se e somente se o primeiro argumento deve ficar a esquerda (ele é considerado "menor" segundo o critério de comparação).

Por exemplo:

```cpp
auto comparador = [](Vereador x, Vereador y) { return x.votos > y.votos; };

Vereador angelo = { "Angelo Orlando", 6580 };
Vereador paulo = { "Paulo Furini",   3985 }

auto resultado = comparador(angelo, paulo);
```

O valor armazendo em resultado será `true`, justamente porque, ao ordenar, `angelo` deveria ficar a esquerda de `paulo`.

---

Com a questão do lambda fora do caminho e entendo o que é esperado do terceiro argumento, fica a questão de quais seriam os argumentos de fato passados para o comparador. Na real? Não importa *muito* o como, essa é a graça.

Para fazer uma ordenação absoluta, você só precisa ser capaz de comparar dois valores por vez. Tome, por exemplo, um `insertionsort` escrito com um comparador genérico e um iterador também genérico:

```cpp
template<class RandomIt, class Comparador>
void insertionsort(RandomIt comeco, RandomIt fim, Comparador cmp) {
    for (RandomIt it = comeco + 1; it != fim ; it++) {
        for (RandomIt it2 = it; it2 != comeco; it2--) {
            RandomIt prev = it2 - 1;
            if (cmp(*it2, *prev)) {
              auto e = *it2;
              *it2 = *prev;
              *prev = e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como seria chamado isso? [Um exemplo](https://ideone.com/PMktu1):

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 3, 2, 1};

    insertionsort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a < b;});
    my_for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a) { std::cout << a << std::endl;}); // saída, cada número em sua própria linha: 1 2 3 3
    return 0;
}
```

Note que, ao chamar a minha função de ordenação, eu não me preocupei em como era o algoritmo de ordenação. Internamente ele poderia funcionar de qualquer jeito. Implementações comuns de ordenação normalmente incluem (mas não se limitam a):

- [TimSort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)
- [QuickSort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [MergeSort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Eu escolhi `insertionsort` pela simples facilidade de implementação. Poderia usar um `bubblesort`:

```cpp
template<class RandomIt, class Comparador>
void bubblesort(RandomIt comeco, RandomIt fim, Comparador cmp) {
    for (RandomIt it = fim - 1; it != comeco ; it--) {
        for (RandomIt it2 = comeco; it2 != it; it2++) {
            RandomIt next = it2 + 1;
            if (!cmp(*it2, *next)) {
              auto e = *it2;
              *it2 = *next;
              *next = e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Que de todo jeito a maneira de chamar seria exatamente a mesma (ajeitando, claro, para o nome da função):

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 3, 2, 1};

    bubblesort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a < b;});
    my_for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a) { std::cout << a << std::endl;}); // saída, cada número em sua própria linha: 1 2 3 3
    return 0;
}
```

---

Sobre coisas específicas do como o C++ faz as mágicas:

> como os argumentos são passados para a função?

O C++ acessa o conteúdo do iterador. Eu posso pegar o conteúdo de um `std::vector::iterator it` usando o operador de derreferenciamento `*it`. Essa pode ser uma das estratégias usadas.

Eu tenho a suspeita que, na função lambda, declará-la como `[]( Vereador& x, Vereador& y ){ return x.votos > y.votos; }` possa ser melhor na lida de objetos grandes, mas é mais suspeita do que por conhecimento consolidado ou prática.

> como é usado o valor retornado para ordenar os valores?

Se você comparar um elemento `a` com o elemento `b` e retornar `true`, você sabe que `a` deveria vir antes de `b`. Se você pegou `a` mais próximo do começo do vetor, não precisa fazer nada; caso contrário, `b` é o elemento mais próximo do vetor, então precisa fazer o *swap* desses valores.

O retorno `false` é análogo, sempre tentando manter a ordem.

> como ocorre a troca de posições, esse tal de *swap*?

Provavelmente eu creio que se use a função [`std::swap`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/), mas funciona também fazendo uma troca de valores de modo mais tradicional. Isso é algo que pode ser feito de acordo com a implementação.

Answer (score 1):

### Questão 1

> Quais argumentos estariam recebendo os parâmetros x e y?

`x` e `y` serão 2 instâncias de `Vereador` e a função será chamada sempre que o `sort()` precisar comparar dois `Vereador`, com os valores deles em `x` e `y`

em

```
 sort( campanha.begin(), campanha.end(),
        []( Vereador x, Vereador y ){ return x.votos > y.votos; } );
```

Veja o protótipo de sort() [em CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

[image: sort() em cppReference]

`campanha` é um vetor de `Vereador` então é isso que os iteradores vão retornar

```
    vector<Vereador> campanha
    {
        { "Angelo Orlando", 6580 },
        { "Paulo Furini",   3985 },
        { "Augusto Jacob",  9025 },
        { "Chico Sardelli", 5900 }
    };
```

### Questão 2

> como o sort iria usar o valor do retorno para ordenar o vector?

Para poder classificar um grupo de qualquer coisa é preciso poder comparar duas delas. Essa é a noção de ordem. E é isso que você está procurando. Por isso `sort()`, como `qsort()` em C, precisa da noção de `<`, de menor. Seja qual for a maneira que vai usar para classificar você precisa comparar os vereadores para saber qual vem antes de qual na ordem final.

Assim `sort()` não precisa saber o que está classificando, porque você diz como comparar dois elementos.

Se sua classe for trivialmente comparável, ou seja, se puder usar o operador `<` para comparar dois deles, pode omitir a função de classificação e usar apenas

```
 sort( campanha.begin(), campanha.end() );
```

Se puder usar `ranges::sort()` em C++20 pode escrever apenas `sort(campanha)` se a classe tiver o operador `<` e omitir os iteradores, classificando o vetor todo usando a noção de `<` para o que quer que tenha dentro do vetor. Imagine um vetor de `int` por exemplo.

#### Exemplos em C++

#### 1. Implementando < para não precisar do terceiro parâmetro

```
struct Vereador
{
    string nome;
    int votos;

    friend bool operator< (const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.nome < outro.nome; };

};
```

Note que a partir disso um `Vereador` será menor que outro `Vereador` se o nome em ordem alfabética por menor. Podia ser o CPF se tivesse isso no registro, ou `um` ter mais votos que `outro`, ou menos.

Uma vez que implementou isso para a classe não precisa mais do terceiro parâmetro no `sort()` e pode escrever

```
    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end());
```

**Então porque existe o tal parâmetro?** Porque é mais dinâmico poder comparar na hora e se pode usar um critério diferente a cada chamada.

#### 2. Usando `functor` para definir o outro parâmetro

Aqui se define o operador `()` para a classe `Vereador`. E o resultado dessa função é classificar os caras em ordem crescente de votos.

```
 struct Vereador
{
    string nome;
    int    votos;

    bool operator()(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.votos < outro.votos; };

    friend bool operator<(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.nome < outro.nome; };
};
```

E se pode escrever

```
    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), Vereador());
```

#### 3. usando uma função qualquer para comparar `Vereador`

Em C++ pode usar *free_functions*, funções que não estão dentro de nenhuma classe, para fazer as comparações de que o `sort()` precisa.

```
struct Vereador
{
    string nome;
    int    votos;

    bool operator()(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.votos < outro.votos; };

    friend bool operator<(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.nome < outro.nome; };
};

const bool free_function( const Vereador& A, const Vereador& B)
{    return A.nome.length() < B.nome.length();};
```

E se pode escrever como em `C`

```
    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), free_function);
```

#### 4. Usando uma função lambda como parâmetro

Na própria linha do comando, como no seu exemplo, se pode colocar o código da função. A menos de uma função simples, *one-liner*, usar o código misturado no meio da chamada a `sort()` pode ser ruim de ler, estilo `javascript`.

```
        []( Vereador x, Vereador y ){ return x.votos > y.votos; } );
```

E escrever então

```
    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(),
        []( Vereador x, Vereador y ){ return x.votos > y.votos; } );
```

### Um programa completo com todos os exemplos acima

#### Para ficar mais curto, implementando o operador *left bit shift* `<<` para `Vereador`

```
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& saida, const Vereador& V)
    {
        saida << V.nome << "\tVotos: " << V.votos << "\n";
        return saida;
    }
```

Assim centraliza a formatação de Vereador e o texto fica mais legível:

```
    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end()); // operador < da classe
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem de nome\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;
```

#### Separando a função lambda para ficar junto com os outros critérios de exemplo

Usando auto se pode levar a definição da comparação para o início do programa, onde estão as outras:

```
struct Vereador
{
    string nome;
    int    votos;

    bool operator()(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.votos < outro.votos; };

    friend bool operator<(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.nome < outro.nome; };

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& saida, const Vereador& V)
    {
        saida << V.nome << "\tVotos: " << V.votos << "\n";
        return saida;
    }
};

const bool free_function( const Vereador& A, const Vereador& B)
{    return A.nome.length() < B.nome.length();};

auto uma = []( Vereador x, Vereador y )
{    return x.votos > y.votos; };
```

#### main() testando esses casos

Usando essas mudanças o código fica possívelmente mais fácil de ler:

```
int main(void)
{
    vector<Vereador> campanha
    {
        { "Angelo Orlando III", 6580 },
        { "Paulo  Furini Jr.",   3985 },
        { "Augusto Jacob",  9025 },
        { "Chico Sardelli Senior", 5900 }
    };

    cout << "==>\tOrdem original:\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), uma ); // lambda
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem decrescente de votos\n";   
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end()); // operador < da classe
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem de nome\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), Vereador()); // functor
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem crescente de votos\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), free_function); // free function
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem crescente de tamanho no nome\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Saida do exemplo completo

```
==>     Ordem original:
Angelo Orlando III      Votos: 6580
Paulo  Furini Jr.       Votos: 3985
Augusto Jacob   Votos: 9025
Chico Sardelli Senior   Votos: 5900


==>     depois do sort, em ordem decrescente de votos
Augusto Jacob   Votos: 9025
Angelo Orlando III      Votos: 6580
Chico Sardelli Senior   Votos: 5900
Paulo  Furini Jr.       Votos: 3985


==>     depois do sort, em ordem de nome
Angelo Orlando III      Votos: 6580
Augusto Jacob   Votos: 9025
Chico Sardelli Senior   Votos: 5900
Paulo  Furini Jr.       Votos: 3985


==>     depois do sort, em ordem crescente de votos
Paulo  Furini Jr.       Votos: 3985
Chico Sardelli Senior   Votos: 5900
Angelo Orlando III      Votos: 6580
Augusto Jacob   Votos: 9025


==>     depois do sort, em ordem crescente de tamanho no nome
Augusto Jacob   Votos: 9025
Paulo  Furini Jr.       Votos: 3985
Angelo Orlando III      Votos: 6580
Chico Sardelli Senior   Votos: 5900
```

Usando seu código, apenas aumentei o tamanho de alguns nomes e testei com as funções de comparação descritas acima.

Espero que tenha entendido a mecânica disso.

#### O programa completo

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

struct Vereador
{
    string nome;
    int    votos;

    bool operator()(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.votos < outro.votos; };

    friend bool operator<(const Vereador& um, const Vereador& outro)
    { return um.nome < outro.nome; };

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& saida, const Vereador& V)
    {
        saida << V.nome << "\tVotos: " << V.votos << "\n";
        return saida;
    }
};

const bool free_function( const Vereador& A, const Vereador& B)
{    return A.nome.length() < B.nome.length();};

auto uma = []( Vereador x, Vereador y )
{    return x.votos > y.votos; };


int main(void)
{
    vector<Vereador> campanha
    {
        { "Angelo Orlando III", 6580 },
        { "Paulo  Furini Jr.",   3985 },
        { "Augusto Jacob",  9025 },
        { "Chico Sardelli Senior", 5900 }
    };
  
    cout << "==>\tOrdem original:\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), uma ); // lambda
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem decrescente de votos\n";   
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end()); // operador < da classe
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem de nome\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), Vereador()); // functor
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem crescente de votos\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    sort(campanha.begin(), campanha.end(), free_function); // free function
    cout << "\n\n==>\tdepois do sort, em ordem crescente de tamanho no nome\n";
    for (auto i : campanha) cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```